# Integrate by parts $2x \ln(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to find the integral of $\displaystyle \int 2x\ln(x+1)dx$ by integrating by parts.
When applying the formula, my second part becomes very complicated, something like $\displaystyle \int \frac{2x}{x+1}$.

I would be glad if someone give me complete solution.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  That could be integrated using partial fractions

Comment: $2x/(x+1)$ can be integrated in a very standard way. I'd recommend reading about integration of rational functions.

Comment: That's what integral calculator gives me for $\int \dfrac{2x}{x+1}$; result =
$ \dfrac{\left(2x+1\right)\ln\left(2x+1\right)-2x}{2}$

Comment: If you substitute $y=\ln(x+1)$ first, you should find it easy to integrate by parts after that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\frac{2x}{x+1}=2\frac x{x+1}=2\left(1-\frac1{x+1}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$ I= \int 2x\ln(x+1)dx=\int \ln(x+1)dx^2=\ln(x+1)x^2-\int \dfrac{x^2}{x+1}  dx,$

$\int \dfrac{x^2}{x+1} dx=\int \dfrac{(x+1)^2-2x-1}{x+1} dx=
\int (x+1+ \dfrac{-2x-2+1}{x+1}) dx=\int( x-1+ \dfrac{1}{x+1} ) dx = \dfrac{(x-1)^2}{2}+ln(x+1)+C1 $

$ I= \int 2x\ln(x+1)dx=(x^2-1)ln(x+1)-\dfrac{(x-1)^2}{2} +C $